# Django: Storing Images Database

Tags: python, django

Earlier I was using default database sqlite3, but today i've changed it to postgresql.

I wants to save the image files in database not in project directory itself. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a good idea to store an image in DB instead `media` folder. But you can use [BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) for this:

**model.py**

```
class MyModel(model.Model):
    image = models.BinaryField(blank=True)
```

**view.py**

```
def image(request):
    image_file = request.FILES['image_file'].file.read()
    MyModel.objects.create(image=image_file)
```

Comment: Why `BinaryField` not `ImageField` ? What are pros and cons of using `ImageField` ?

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar An ImageField is simply a text field that stores the file name only.

Comment: Because of ImageField store images in `MEDIA_ROOT` folder, BinaryField in DB. TS wanna use BD for it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage

Comment: Thanks. Got it. :D

Comment: @Selcuk Sir, it's not just storing the file name, It's storing the entire file in same folder as that of Project. Will it slow down the processes?

Comment: @user8557845 Yes, and you will have cacheability issues as those images can only be served through Django and not using a web server, such as nginx.