# How to upload image to db in django instead of static folder

Tags: python, django

I would like to deploy an image to my page using Django, still in a debig mode. I created a model for the image along some other fields, and all the information is migrated to the database except the image which is storaged in the directory folder for /media/. How can i upload this image to the db and deploy it from there?

class Products(models.Model):

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Storing Images Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460861/django-storing-images-database)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you not to store the image in db instead in the folder. But also if you want, use [BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield)

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image = models.BinaryField(blank=True, null=True)

`   def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

Comment: Hi Rai, thanks for your answer, why would not you recommend this? Is it because it is in debug?

Comment: So because my project supposed to be able to upload pics and documents from x amoint of users, i though the best idea was to store them i  the db

Comment: one major advantage of storing in media folder is you can serve them directly from Nginx web server which is fast and doesn't have to hit your code at all.

Comment: So,  that process is automatic one you go production mode? Is there any limitation on storage size ? I am new at this so just trying to understand where and what my statics folders are going to do once i am ready to deploy.

Comment: you have to give path from Nginx server to serve your Django static files. storage depends on your server size.